# Search from mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am taking input from input type="text", for (class a student is studying in)

I don't know how to  search the user input query from mysql. 
As I have entered 10th in mysql, And a user can search the 10th standard by(ten,tenth,10th,Xth,X,10). As these strings were completely different how can I manage these? I even cannot do best matched string here.

```
<datalist id="coachingCategory">
<option value="12th">
<option value="11th">
<option value="10th">           
</datalist>
```

I am asking about the case if a user input is different, from that of datalist.

Comment: show your code sample please

Answer (score 0):

You can do following things

**Method 1- While Taking Value and Inserting into MySQL (if possible)**

Instead of using text-input field use combobox i.e. `<select>` Tag and similar field while searching.

**Method 2- While Searching**

Assuming, that you cannot change/update the form or the database and you are looking for an alternative option. Well, you can do following things.

- Get the input from the user and save it into a variable; call it
  `$class`
- Now, check the value of `$class` using either switch case or if else
  conditional statement

For example:

```
 $new_class;
 $class=$_POST["class"] // assumed that you are using post method with class field
switch($class)
{
case 10: $new_class=10; break;
case '10th': $new_class=10; break;
case 'tenth': $new_class=10; break;
case 'eleventh': $new_class=11; break;
///and so on

default : //anything that you want to set here as default
}
```

Now, using `like` or equals to (`=`) method you can look for the class in the database using PHP.

Comment: Or if the exact string is known. One could use `IN`

Comment: It's fine , Is  there any way , that we make groups for every class like {10th,10,ten,tenth}, it will search for 10. Can I do this without using switch , if possible